# generating barcode for Barby gem under EAN-13

Tags: ruby, barcode

While attempting to render in HTML a collection of article barcodes and proceeding incrementally to view the data (relative to other objects on tha page), the controller

```
require 'barby/outputter/html_outputter'
require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'
```

and the view invokes

```
<%= this_barcode = article.barcodes.first.barcode %>
<%= this_barcode.class %>
<%# barcode = Barby::EAN13.new(this_barcode) %>
<%# outputter = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new(barcode) %>
<%# barcode.to_html.html_safe %>
     [returns as expected]
8001300303466 String
```

however, when wanting to get the barcode and uncommenting that element it fails to process because `data not valid` for the line `barcode = Barby::EAN13.new(this_barcode)` (also occurs with `barcode = Barby::EAN13.new(this_barcode.to_i)`)

**note**  possibly on garden path here, as there is confusion with [what the wiki suggests](https://github.com/toretore/barby/wiki/Outputters#html) with
`barcode = Barby::DataMatrix.new(number)` as that would generate the error
`uninitialized constant Barby::DataMatrix`

How does one ensure the data is correct for proper rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:
`8001300303466` has 13 characters.  It is the correct barcode.

I was assuming one could submit a correct barcode.  However [line 54 of the gem's ean_13.rb file](https://github.com/toretore/barby/blob/master/lib/barby/barcode/ean_13.rb)
allows a 12 character data element `FORMAT = /^\d{12}$/` and proceeds to calculate the check digit.

Thus,

`<%= barcode = Barby::EAN13.new(this_barcode[0...-1]) %>`

will end up processing the data correctly.